# Mysql date update not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

I have one issue while updating mysql table. I have two fields real_date (Type : varchar(20)), event_date(Type: date()). Below are few values

```
real_date   event_date  event_date(Need to b updated.)
1985-03-20  0000-00-00    1971-03-20
1989-08-20  0000-00-00    1971-08-20 
1993-04-30  0000-00-00    1971-04-30
```

I want to update event_date to as shown above. Fetch month and date from real_date and keep year as 1971. I am using below queries but it doesn't work Can you please help me.

```
Query1 : Update table set event_date= STR_TO_DATE(concat('1971','-',DATE_FORMAT(real_date, "%m-%d")),'%Y-%m-%d') where real_date IS NOT NULL AND real_date != '0000-00-00' AND real_date <> '' AND event_date='0000-00-00'

Query2 : Update table set event_date= STR_TO_DATE(concat('1971','-',SUBSTR(real_date, 6, 5)),'%Y-%m-%d') where real_date IS NOT NULL AND real_date != '0000-00-00' AND real_date <> '' AND event_date='0000-00-00'

Query3 : Update table set event_date=concat('1971-',DATE_FORMAT(real_date, "%m-%d")) where real_date IS NOT NULL AND real_date != '0000-00-00' AND real_date <> '' AND event_date='0000-00-00'
```

But none of above works. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

use `OR`

```
UPDATE TableName 
SET    event_date = CONCAT('1971-', DATE_FORMAT(real_date, '%m-%d')) 
WHERE  real_date IS NOT NULL OR 
       real_date != '0000-00-00' OR 
       real_date <> '' OR 
       event_date = '0000-00-00'
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/00a13/1)

Comment: This will not work because concat() returns string and data type of event_date is date() .

Comment: @KumarSoneta remember that mysql is implicit. So it silently cast the string into date. see the fiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/00a13/1

Comment: @JW. , please check my answer, i like to know your opinion as expert

Answer (score 1):

This may help you.

```
update test set event_date = Date_format(Concat('1971','-', DATE_FORMAT( real_date,  '%m-%d' ), '%Y', '%Y-%m-%d');
```

[See sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/06a3c/1)

Comment: Ohh sorry forgot to include this query . I tried this but it doesn't work

Comment: Even I feel this should work but unfortunately it does not update any row. Where I am able to fetch this data .

Comment: Just realized what was issue. Actually issue was with data ... Some concept of leap Year with Date_format. Otherwise any of other queries where working.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at MySQL [Date and time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

Try this:

```
UPDATE table
SET event_date =
  STR_TO_DATE(
    CONCAT('1971-', DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(real_date, '%Y-%m-%d'), '%m-%d')),
    '%Y-%m-%d'
  )
WHERE real_date IS NOT NULL AND
  real_date != '0000-00-00' AND
  real_date <> '' AND
  event_date = '0000-00-00'
```

The basic idea is: convert the existing string to a date. Pull the month and day from it using format and make a string out of this. Then convert the new string to type DATE. You should familiarize yourself with MySQL [DATE_FORMAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

Comment: Oops. Edited my post to remove an invalid semi-colon. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps all of your update codes are correct. Actually it updates `event_date` in your `tablename`, but when you want to use `select` statement for showing the result, you should use `FORMAT_DATE` for `event_date`.

So instead of

```
SELECT * FROM tableName
```

USE:

```
SELECT real_date,DATE_FORMAT(event_date,'%Y-%m-%d') FROM tableName
```

I mean in `UPDATE` statement it is meaningless to use any date format functions for formatting a date coulmn field. it is meaningful just in `SELECT` statement.